# In a BLE advertising packet of type ADV_NOCONN_IND, must payload data be encoded as ASCII?

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy

I need to send sensor data using Bluetooth Low Energy advertising packets. Specifically, non-connectable advertising (ADV_NOCONN_IND), but not as a beacon. I'm hearing from a device vendor that would be receiving the packets that all data sent in the payload MUST be encoded as ASCII, i.e., binary would not be accepted. I understand this limitation when referring to commands via the API, but not payload data. Is ASCII encoding of the data payload required in the Bluetooth specification? This would be tremendous overhead.

Answer (score 1):

Well in the Bluetooth specification, you can find that advertisement data is binary. Nothing in the standard constraints advertisement data to ASCII.

Advertisement data consists of a list of length-type-value fields. For example "Complete Local Name", "Complete list of 128-bit Service UUIDs", "Manufacturer Specific Data" and so on. The specification of each field constraints what kind of data they can contain.

For example, the "Complete Local Name" field shall contain the device's Local Name encoded as a UTF-8 encoded string.

Manufacturer Specific data consists of two bytes identifying a manufacturer id, followed by manufacturer specific bytes. It could be that your vendor for example says that a field of this type, using the vendor's Bluetooth SIG registered company id, must only contain ASCII characters.

The same thing applies to Service data. It's up to the designer of that Service to define what kind of content the advertisement data should contain.